# Flex not running properly

Tags: windows, flex-lexer

I have installed flex windows (lex yacc). When I click execute from exe directly it doesn't run the exe.

It shows like this:

[image: problem image]

Error:

> 'explorer.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command

This is the link to the software that I have installed [flex](http://techapple.net/2014/07/flex-windows-lex-and-yacc-flex-and-bison-installer-for-windows-xp788-1/)

Comment: It looks `C:\Windows` is not set in your `PATH` environment variable! Please try that and check if it helps.

Comment: thanks . it works for me .  problem solved.